# Package uploaded on Bintray but Gradle resolution failed

Tags: android, maven, gradle, bintray, jcenter

I have an uploaded package on my Bintray repository as you can see [here](https://bintray.com/frlgrd/maven/animated-edit-text).

- [Here](https://gist.github.com/frlgrd/63cc6003a15a3252a86a3cbf51bf3d64) is my library module build.gradle file
- [Here](https://gist.github.com/frlgrd/1754394627669225f39627f7271f0804) is my deploy.gradle file
- [Here](https://gist.github.com/frlgrd/701ca4599afe87f6e2f71ba9da331cab) is my deploy.properties file

The problem is I can't resolve the dependency with a standard `compile 'com.frlgrd:animated-edit-text:0.3@aar'`.
My library contains resources, this is why I need `@aar` suffix.

I get this error when I compile the "test" projet which use the dependency :

```
Failed to resolve: com.frlgrd:animated-edit-text:0.3
```

And in this project, I have this root build.gradle file

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On Bintray, in the package page, there is an "Add to jcenter" button. I didn't see it at the beginning but then, I did and I clicked on it and wait for few hours to fix my problem.[image: Add to jcenter button (lost around flashy green elements, it should be more visible according to me)]

Answer (score 0):

> I can't resolve the dependency with a standar compile 'com.frlgrd:animated-edit-text:0.3@aar'. My library contains resources, this is why I need @aar suffix.

Using an artifact notation (as `@aar`) means that you want to download only the aar artifact, and no dependencies since the existing module descriptors are ignored.

In your case you doesn't need the aar notation since in the jcenter repo you have only the aar file (it is not related to the resources)

In any case using the @aar notation if you want to download the dependencies, you should add `transitive=true`.

```
compile('xxxxxx@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for details about `@aar` I am a bit confused about it. But I still can't resolve my dependency with : 
compile ('com.frlgrd:animated-edit-text:0.3@aar'){
        transitive = true
    }

Comment: Can you explain me why ?

Comment: What kind of issue do you receive? Sorry for silly question, did you add the jcenter() repo in the repositories block?

Comment: jcenter() was in the repositories block (I just edited my question)

Comment: I checked your library. It is in bintray https://bintray.com/frlgrd/maven/animated-edit-text but it is not sync with jcenter yet http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/frlgrd/

Comment: So I just have to wait ? I think I do, because, for an other library, I had the same problem and now (several month later) I can get it as a dependency. Maybe you should update your answer then I will accept the the answer. Thank you !

Comment: @FrançoisL. may be the sync requires a few hours to be completed.

Comment: @FrançoisL. It works now. And it is not necessary to use aar notation

Comment: I kwon why my dependency was not pushed on jcenter. There is an "Add to Jcenter" button on Bintray. I didn't see it... I will answer my question but thank you for your help @Gabriele Mariotti !